# Returning result from asynchronous operation in MVC (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, model-view-controller

I have this problem: My controller asks my Model to load some data for me, because the controller needs that data to populate the view. The model asks the data store for the data, which then again queries the database. My Model sends in a block which contains the logic to handle the result.

Then the problems comes; how to return this data to the controller? Since it is asynchronous, I can't put a return inside the block, or outside it, because I don't know when it is completed.

I have thought about 2 ways of fixing this;

- Have Controller pass in a block as a callback to my Model, which then again calls that callback in its own callback block.
- Have my Model post a notification which my controller can listen to.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

EDIT: To try to clarify #1 on the list (don't have any code): My Controller calls, lets say, `saveStuff:callback:` in the Model and passes `stuff` and a callback block. The Model then asks the data store to save `stuff` and passes its own callback to the data store. What I then do is to call the Controllers callback inside the Models callback. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: Sounds like good approaches to me.

Comment: hi ... this line is not clear: My Model sends in a block which contains the logic to handle the result. I think if you can add some code to your question, it will be easy for us to help.

Comment: +1 to the idea of posting message to notification centre. It maintains the lose coupling between controller and Model. It will also benefit in case you want to multicast the message

Comment: @Miraaj I've tried to explain it a bit better. I don't have any code at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution is pass a block to the model as completion handler and then call it. Something like this

```
// model implementation
-(void)loadDatabaseOnCompletion:(void(^)(id result))completionHandler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // loading data from server
        completionHandler(result);
    });
}

...
// from ViewController
[model loadDatabaseOnCompletion:^(id result) {

}];
```

Comment: If the callback is to a view controller, you probably don't want to be making it on a concurrent queue.

Comment: So you can call callback in the main queue:
`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    completionHandler(result);
});`

Comment: @ChrisDevereux why not? I've dont that now, and it seems to be working. What is the difference between that and calling them on the main queue?

Comment: the difference is if you want to change UI, for example change frame or load image in a UIImageView, you need to do it only in the main thread.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Fry Oh, yes, I know that. Right now I am wrapping functionality regarding the UI in `dispatch_async`. Perhaps it is better to just wrap the entire callback in it, makes for clear code.